# javascript: what is the best way to do synchronous programming

Tags: javascript, synchronous

What is the best way to do synchronous programming with Javascript?

Comment: Just write the code? It's synchronous by default. Also see [ask] and what not to ask [help/dont-ask]

Comment: I am sorry it is not, if you console log start then you get a content of a file you console log it then you console log finish, you end up with start finish then the content of your file, as fas as I know this is not sync, NB: do not comment just to get stats :p

Comment: Javascript has the ability to execute in a way that is asynchronous.  And the subsequent interactions with browsers, databases, etc. can appear to be occuring asynchronous because of how the computer is processing it.  However, Javascript itself IS synchronous.

Comment: The problem you are having with the console log is an appropriate problem to address here.

Comment: Kirk, but how to make sure that my code is runing sync and does not switch to async mode

Comment: who voted this question as "primary opinion based"? this question simply doesn't make sense at all, without any kind of primary opinions

Comment: console log was just an example, if I want to save the content of the file in a variable than do something with it in a second function, the second fucntion will run with an undefined variable since the first one didn't finish to process the file and get it's contenet and the function two will start

Comment: does it have something to do with functions an how you declare them?

Comment: That's because the file operation is running outside of the JavaScript runtime. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript runtime is a single-threaded environment - - that is, it executes a single command at a time (synchronous).  However, the browser that hosts the JavaScript runtime runs in a multi-threaded environment (the operating system). This means that while the JavaScript runtime can only process one line of code at a time, the browser can be doing something else while that is happening.

So, to do synchronous programming, you don't need to do anything special. Just write code. But, if that code asks the browser to do some work (through any one of the many Web API's, such as an AJAX request, a Geolocation request, a `setTimeout()`, etc.), the browser will perform those operations asynchronously from the JavaScript runtime.  In those cases, you will need to set up a callback function for when the asynchronous operation is complete - you can't know when that will be, but you can be prepared for when it finishes.

Here's an example of code that does not involve a Web API (synchronous) call:

```js
var x = "First";
console.log(x); 

var y = "Third";
var z = "Second";

function test(){
  console.log(z); 
}

console.log(y);  

test();

// This code will be run synchronously. The output will be:
"First"
"Third"
"Second"
```

Now, we'll introduce a Web API call (`setTimeout()`), which is handled outside of the JavaScript runtime. This example clearly demonstrates that the JS runtime cannot do two things at once.

```js
console.log("...starting...");


// Note that the timer is passed 0, which would seem to indicate that it should run the 
// passed function immediately, but that won't happen because the JS runtime MUST complete
// the synchronous processing of the current execution context and go into an idle state
// before any new code can be executed
setTimeout(function(){ 
  console.log("Message from setTimeout()...COMPLETE");
}, 0); // <-- NOTE THE ZERO (AS IN RUN RIGHT NOW)

// This message will be shown before the setTimeout message because the JS runtime
// cannot do two things at once. It MUST finish this code block first.
console.log("...working...");


// Result:  "...starting...", "...working...", "Message from setTimeout()...COMPLETE"
```